# Почему кнопка обрезается на ios?

Tags: css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.rectangle-29
{
    width: 211px;
    background-color: white !important;
    color: black;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #2c2a3b;
    border-width: 0.5px;
    cursor: pointer;
   -webkit-appearance: none;
}
@media (max-width: 750px)
.rectangle-29 {
    height: 54px !important;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin: 10px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="group-22">
    <div class="rectangle-29 page_sor button_sor" id="2">
        <div class="sor-div7">Соревнования по Школе танца</div>
    </div>
</div>
```